# How to remove string using preg_replace?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$content = "Tuesday 28th May 2013 07:22<br/><br/>Hello world";
```

And using code:

```
preg_replace("s/(<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/", "", $content);
```

But result wrong, how to remove this string for result is `"Hello world"`;

Comment: It's not clear what you want to remove...

Comment: Remove on what conditions? Is the string always "Hello world"? Everything after a `<br />`? After two `<br />`s? After a date?

Comment: `$content = "Hello world";` that'll remove it for ya :)

Comment: If you just want everything after the last <br />, and the exact formatting of the tag does not vary in your input text, have you thought of using $output_array = explode("<br/>", $content); and then selecting the last element of $output_array?

Answer (score 0):

As with any programming language there are hundreds of ways to do everything. Here's how to do it with `preg_replace()` since that was your example attempt. Not sure about the question's ultimate goal... but here are a few examples:

```
$content = "Tuesday 28th May 2013 07:22<br/><br/>Hello world";
```

Return "Hello World" only:

```
$hello = preg_replace('!^([^<]+)(<[^>]+>){2}!','',$content);
```

Return Time Portion only:

```
$time = preg_replace('!^([^<]+)(<[^>]+>){2}(.*)$!',"$1",$content);
```

Removes the tags (`strip_tags()` is usually better for this, but you've no wordspace in this case):

```
$clean_content = preg_replace('!^([^<]+)(<[^>]+>){2}(.*)$!',"$1 $3",$content);
```

Print out the statements:

```
echo $hello."<br>";
echo $time."<br>";
echo $clean_content."<br>";
```

**Output** (I'm adding the `<br>` tag for readability in the browser):

> Hello world
>
> Tuesday 28th May 2013 07:22
>
> Tuesday 28th May 2013 07:22 Hello world